# In the Doctor Who universe, who is the mysterious lady who carries the blue journal?

Tags: doctor-who

In "Silence in the Library" we meet a strange woman who claims to have seen the Doctor before. In point of fact, she claims to have seen him a lot and The Doctor claims to have never seen her before. She carries a blue TARDIS shaped journal that contains "spoilers" of the adventures the Doctor and her supposedly went on.

This woman, who may be in love with the Doctor, appears a few more times during the series (across Doctor regenerations). Who is she? And who is she in relation to the Doctor? A wife? An enemy? Who?

Comment: That's the story line, we don't know yet.

Comment: So since we are all waiting on the answer, see meta discussion http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/502/whats-the-procedure-when-a-question-is-not-answerable-yet, I've decided to not mark an answer until we know what River Song's relationship with the Doctor is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You mean River Song?  We don't know much so far.  She was imprisoned in the Stormcage Holding Facility for killing, "A very good man. Best man I've ever known."  Apparently each time the Doctor meets her, it's earlier in her timeline and later in The Doctor's.  So in their first meeting in *Silence of the Library* she knew him very well, and he met her for the first time.  She's shown extreme knowledge and familiarity with the TARDIS, piloting it better than The Doctor does.  Each time The Doctor meets her, she references their next adventure, indicating that she does in fact know The Doctor's future.

In the season 6 episode 7, [A Good Man Goes To War](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/A_Good_Man_Goes_to_War), we learn that River is

> Amy and Rory's child.  Conceived in the TARDIS as it was traversing the [Time Vortex](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Vortex), the baby absorbed some vortex energy, becoming part Time Lord.  She was abducted as a baby by [Madame Kovarian](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Kovarian) and [The Church](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Church).  At some point after that, she ended up on Earth as a young child, where The Silence cared for her.  They built a spacesuit for her that would sustain and protect her.  Somehow River escaped from the suit and as a child, was last seen starving to death, and then regenerating in a city on Earth.

Much more detail can be found at the [Doctor Who wiki](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/River_Song).

Comment: River Song's relationship with the doctor is not known yet. Wow, I guess this makes my question unanswerable until its known. I thought I just missed something big, but apparently not.

Comment: Nope, Moffat seems to be big on multi-season arcs, and the mystery of River Song is one of them.

Comment: Huh? Please don't think bad of me but who is Moffat? As I go to Google... Ah... a writer. Hey multi-season arcs are very intriguing... lots of money for the writters.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry.  Steven Moffat's the showrunner.  He took over at the start of series 5, when Matt Smith took over as the Doctor.

Comment: So I should be thanking Moffat for all the intriguing plot lines and arcs... (well since series 5).

Comment: I'm answering this one as a best answer, because you gave me all the in cannon knowledge, even through a good portion of her is a mystery. A good portion of the question is answered here.